# Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Implementing this with ggplot2 and shiny by having two input selections for the date ranges and have the plot adjust the x(date values) adjust accordingly, however, I get this error below:

```
Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

How can I resolve this? Here is my code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)



data <- read.csv("C:/Users/user/Documents/R/R-3.3.1/R CODE/MyData2.csv", header = TRUE) # reading .csv
newdata <- as.data.frame(data) # converting csv to DF
newdata$event_date <- as.factor(newdata$event_date)

str(newdata)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("select", label = h3("Select Model"), 
              choices = list("Toyota Camry", "Nissan Altima")),

  dateInput("strtdate", "Select start date:"),

  dateInput("enddate", "Select end date:"),

  plotOutput("hist")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$hist <- renderPlot({

    df <- newdata %>% select(event_date,PlatformName,total_events) %>% filter(PlatformName == input$select) %>% group_by(event_date, PlatformName) %>% summarize(total_events = sum(total_events))

    gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x= event_date, y = total_events, group =PlatformName)) +
      geom_line(aes(color = PlatformName)) +


      labs(title="Total Events vs. Time", x="Event Dates", y="Total Events") +

                aes(xmin = input$strtdate, 
                    xmax = input$enddate) +


      theme(plot.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold", hjust = 0.5),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=10, angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=5),
            axis.title.x=element_text(size=10),
            axis.title.y=element_text(size=10)) 

    print(gg)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: When asking for help you should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. If you have date values in your data, make sure they are parsed as dates (either they have `class()` `Date` or `POSIXct` or something). Right now you seem to be making them factors and that's not going to make things easier for R to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the issue. Just needed to convert the specific date column in a date format.

Via:

```
newdata$event_date <- as.Date(newdata$event_date)
```

Thus, new code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)



data <- read.csv("C:/Users/user/Documents/R/R-3.3.1/R CODE/MyData2.csv", header = TRUE) # reading .csv
newdata <- as.data.frame(data) # converting csv to DF


newdata$event_date <- as.factor(newdata$event_date) #CODE IMPLEMENTAITON


str(newdata)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("select", label = h3("Select Model"), 
              choices = list("Toyota Camry", "Nissan Altima")),

  dateInput("strtdate", "Select start date:"),

  dateInput("enddate", "Select end date:"),

  plotOutput("hist")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$hist <- renderPlot({

    df <- newdata %>% select(event_date,PlatformName,total_events) %>% filter(PlatformName == input$select) %>% group_by(event_date, PlatformName) %>% summarize(total_events = sum(total_events))

    gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x= event_date, y = total_events, group =PlatformName)) +
      geom_line(aes(color = PlatformName)) +


      labs(title="Total Events vs. Time", x="Event Dates", y="Total Events") +

                aes(xmin = input$strtdate, 
                    xmax = input$enddate) +


      theme(plot.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold", hjust = 0.5),
            axis.text.x=element_text(size=10, angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5),
            axis.text.y=element_text(size=5),
            axis.title.x=element_text(size=10),
            axis.title.y=element_text(size=10)) 

    print(gg)

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```